# I need to translate a sql-query releated sentence but don't know what it means

Tags: php

I need to translate this sentece:

> Consider loosening your query with OR. bike OR shed will often show more results than bike shed.

What is meant by bike and shed? Are these some symbols on the keyboard?

Comment: `bike` and `shed` are examples

Comment: I know I shouldn't laugh as I can see why there's confusion but this has brightened my morning. Yeah they're just example uses. `bike`, `shed` and `bikeshed` are query examples :)

Comment: Oh no :-) Sometimes it can be so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is meant by this is that searching for the string `"bike shed"` will yield less results than searching for entries that contains either `"bike"` OR `"shed"`.

Suppose you have three rows:

```
1: I like my bike
2: Buy my shed
3: Where is the bike shed
```

Searching for `"bike"` yields rows 1 and 3.

Searching for `"shed"` yields rows 2 and 3.

Searching for `"bike shed"` yields row 3.

Searching for `"bike"` OR `"shed"` yields rows 1, 2 and 3.